# DB Schema Design - Designing multiple many to many tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am trying to design a DB that has multiple many to many junction tables but each many to many is a cascading option based on previous tables.

For Example: Let's begin with four tables with their primary keys.

> Style table --> Style ID (PK)
>      Fabric table --> FabricID (PK)
>      Body table --> BodyID (PK)
>      Color table --> ColorID (PK)

A User chooses a Style and then a Fabric, so this is easy to define the many to many.

> StyleFabric table --> StyleID, FabricID (Composite PK)

Now this is where I get confused. The User after choosing Style and Fabric can now choose Body. So I created a table called:

> StyleFabricBody table --> StyleID, FabricID, BodyID  (Composite PK)

Now Based on Style,Fabric and Body, the user can select a color

> StyleFabricBodyColor table --> StyleID, FabricID, BodyID, ColorID (Composite PK)

Hopefully you can see the pattern by now and I have 5 more tables to add.

Is this a correct approach to connect the main tables ?

Comment: You could have a single table - Item (or Product or whatever you want to call the user selection) with UserID and all 9 other IDs representing style, fabric, body, color, etc. BTW, this does not make it a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Never mind, deleting my old comment, I missed the bit about cascading choices...so to clarify, you mean that if a user selects style X, then they are limited to fabrics Y,Z,A, and if they then select fabric Y, they are limited to body B,C, or D, etc.?

Comment: @mallan1121 Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: I would relegate the cascading logic to the front end. Databases should establish the relationship between entities, not data points IMHO.

Comment: I imagine cascading things in the primary key like that is going to end up giving you a ton of duplicated data and it just doesn't seem like the right solution. Is it really the case that color is determined by body, and not just fabric, for example? Do the dependencies really cascade in that way, so that every possible combination of Style + Fabric + Body has a different set of valid color choices? That would seem odd. I'd verify that first.

Comment: Both of the above are good points. This sounds like something better suited to a more lightweight solution like a config file. If you really need to keep it in a database, it might be better to go with a less normalized design for holding these configurations.

Comment: @Anand A single table was one of the options I considered but I was hoping to define the many to many relationship so that it's easier for me using Entity Framework to pull in the related data.

Comment: @pmbAustin Initial designs that I got shows a config/admin menu where an admin would basically pick and choose the different type of combinations for each style + fabric + body etc. I am still waiting for the client's response.

Comment: Basically, it seems like you'd want a static table (more or less... editable by someone but mostly constant) that enumerates all the "valid" combinations of these possible parameters. You wouldn't cascade primary keys, you'd do something similar to the answer below, and filter with WHERE clauses to narrow down the potential values as users make selections.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be enough, you don't need more than one table:

```
create table dbo.UserChoice
(
    Id int identity(1, 1) primary key nonclustered,

    UserId   int not null,

    StyleId  int not null,
    FabricId int not null,
    BodyId   int not null,
    ColorId  int not null,
    ...,

    constraint FK_UserChoice_UserId   foreign Key (UserId)   references dbo.User   (Id),

    constraint FK_UserChoice_StyleId  foreign Key (StyleId)  references dbo.Style  (Id),
    constraint FK_UserChoice_FabricId foreign Key (FabricId) references dbo.Fabric (Id),
    constraint FK_UserChoice_BodyId   foreign Key (BodyId)   references dbo.Body   (Id),
    constraint FK_UserChoice_ColorId  foreign Key (ColorId)  references dbo.Color  (Id),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I suggest you have the structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE Choosable
(
    ChoosableId int,            -- This is PK
    Name        varchar(10),    -- This can have values 'Style', 'Fabric', 'Body', 'Color'
)

Data in this table

Style1
Style2
Fab1
Fab2
Fab3
Body1
Body2
Blue
Red
Gray


CREATE TABLE Choices
(
    ChoiceId       int,     -- This is PK
    ChoosableId    int,     -- This is FK to Choosable.ChoosableId
    ParentId       int      -- This is FK to ChoiceId
)

Structure for this table can support below data

Style1
    Fab1
        Body1
            Red
            Blue
        Body2
            Red
    Fab2
        Body1
            Blue
            Gray
            Red
```